# Confused about "business"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

What does *business* mean in the following sentence?

> He's in the frozen food *business*.

Is he a businessman, like the head of a company who actually do the selling and buying frozen food?

Is he just someone who works in that field? Can I say the same if he's a financial analyst or an accountant of a company that specializes in frozen food?

Comment: It's *possible* he's a lowly shop assistant working behind the counter selling frozen food, but usually the cited usage would imply more than that. Perhaps he actually runs his own frozen food business, but he might just be a ***sales rep*** who specialises in selling frozen food. The usage is perhaps less likely for someone who just works in the "back office" handling admin tasks (I think maybe it's more likely with the sales rep because his *income* varies according to how well he promotes the business, but I'm not too sure about that).

Comment: I can distinguish a nuance - Mr Honda **is** in the motorcycle business, but Joe Smith who sells spare parts in a dealer's store **works** in the motorcycle business.

Comment: I worked for decades as both direct employee and independent consultant providing software solutions to public transport *(bus companies)*, but I doubt I'd ever have said *I'm in the public transport business.* If anything, I'd have said something like *I'm in the software services business*.

Comment: If I spent money to build a sawmill and employ staff to make planks, poles, etc, out of trees and sell them I could say "I am going into the timber business" and after it started I would be in the timber business.

Answer (score 3):

It is defined as an "occupation, profession, or trade" at [Dictionary.com](https://dictionary.com).

So that means you can use it for both: the head of a company, or a low-class waiter (both having an occupation in the business).

And hence, you can say the same for people who are financial analysts or accountants of a company that specializes in frozen food.